# DataMapper: tag to key relationship?

Tags: mule, datamapper, mule-studio

I'm using the DataMapper component in MuleStudio. I want to transform data that I have in this format

```
<item type="1" name="data">
    <children name="action">
        <values>login.01</values>
    <children>
</item>
```

to something like this

```
<item>
    <action>login.01</action>
</item>
```

Is this possible through Mule? Or will I need to make a custom Java parser?

Comment: Is the source real XML or not? I'm asking because `<children>` is not closed by `</children>` but by `<children>`, which isn't XML.

Comment: Oops, sorry I just copied a bit of it for this post, nice catch. But yeah the real file will have a closing tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the source is XML, no need to use DataMapper: a simple XSL-T transformer will do the trick:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <item>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </item>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="children">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="values/text()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What about if the source file had some elements with a different namespace? For example, 
`<ns:items>
<ns:item type="1" name="data">
    <children name="action">
        <values>login.01</values>
    <children>
</ns:item>
</ns:items>`

Comment: Just declare the namespaces on the `stylesheet` element and use them in the `template`s.